# Unable to restart mysql ( See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-5.7

I'm unable to restart mysql.

`journalctl -xe` gives the following output

```
Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu audit[4075]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/4075/status" pid=4075 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r"

Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu audit[4075]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=4075 comm="mysqld" requested_

Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu audit[4075]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/4075/status" pid=4075 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="r"

Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1538631350.144:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/4075/status" pid=407

Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1538631350.144:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/"

Oct 04 11:05:50 ubuntu kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1538631350.144:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/4075/status" pid=407

Oct 04 11:05:51 ubuntu sudo[4097]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/sda

Oct 04 11:05:51 ubuntu sudo[4097]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)

Oct 04 11:05:52 ubuntu sudo[4097]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: cmd 25/00:20:00:12:f3/00:00:53:00:00/e0 tag 24 dma 16384 in

                                        res 51/40:00:1e:12:f3/00:00:53:00:00/00 Emask 0x9 (media error)

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: error: { UNC }

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 53 f3 12 00 00 00 20 00

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1408438814

Oct 04 11:05:55 ubuntu kernel: ata3: EH complete

Oct 04 11:05:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thanks, the format looks fine.I just tried to paste the output of "journalctl -xe".

Comment: But please note: one could consider your question off-topic. This isnt really about programming, but about admin work for a specific database. I think your question might better go to segfault.com for example.